# Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of For raising height of sprite the preferences

Tags: android, sprite, sharedpreferences

I know this has been asked before and I went through all the answers and nope this ain't that, and yes I have the activity named in the manifest so it's not that.
Here's my problem:
I have a sprite moving across the screen and when in the window where you choose the livewallpaper, I have a preference that lets the user choose the height (so they can move the sprite up or down) the only problem is the sprite is constantly moving so when they use the seekbar to move the sprite up or down I get the old 'Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of" Now if I go out and come back in again of course this stop and restarts it and the new preference hight is already in their so it moves to the new height then but not in the live preview. 
Here is the sprite code:

```
private void addShipOne() { 
        int heightPosition = (screenSized / 2) - (screenSized / /*this.bigShipHeight*/gettheFreakingHeight());
        int widthPosition = 0;
        Point startPoint = new Point(widthPosition, heightPosition);
        this._shipone.add(new SpaceShipOne(this._context, this, startPoint, 125));
```

(sorry about the method name I was using to test a quick version I was a bit frustrated at that point) lol

It then goes into an OnDraw method then into the render to render it all.

```
public void render(){
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try{

            canvas = this._surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (this._surfaceHolder) {

                this.onDraw(canvas);

            }

        }finally{
            if(canvas != null){
                this._surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   
    }
```

I have another preference that allows the user to choose the frequency of the ships appearing it works fine but it goes from left to right and changes ships then so it updates the frequency then, but the height one doesn't work, I tested the log to make sure the height int goes through and it does so its not that, the only thing I can come up with is the maybe add this when the ship turns left or right, but it does not work while its moving by the looks of it.
this.bigShipHeight is where the new height value goes into ( I was just testing it another way with the gettheFreakingHeight() (I used an if else statement for that method that used the frquency preference instead which does work nicely.
Just to add the full code part.
In the onDraw(Canvas canvas)
I render the _shipone as such

```
for (Renderable renderable : this._shipone) {
            renderable.render(canvas);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I should of looked into the my sprite class first, sorry about this I answered my own question once again and it was too obvious, that's what I get for looking at the code way to long, I should walk away then come back it always is clearer then.

Just in case others run into this issue I'll put the answer.
In my sprite class which SpaceShipOne runs from I just added this

```
this.getSprite().setYPos(this._blimp.gettheFreakingHeight());
```

This updates right away with no window already focused.
I don't know why I didn't see this last night because it is the only place it can be added and be updated right away, all I had to do was set the Y position to the preference instead.
It works like a charm.
Hope this helps someone else out
Sam